# How much electricity bill of rpi3 b+?

Tags: raspbian

I wonder if it is ok to turn on rpi3 all day?
I worried about electric bill and 
How long rpi3 can endure?

Comment: In terms on how long you can run a RPi: I had a RPi1 permanently running for over a year, no problems.

Comment: The lifespan of your Pi is limited mostly by that on which it stores data.

Comment: "How long rpi3 can endure?" -> That remains to be seen since most of them are still around.  It is not unusual to leave them running 24/7.

Comment: In terms of endurance, it would depend on your usage of the RPI. If you are running an application with low disk write and the RPI is physically not situated in a harsh environment (e.g an outdoor cabinet with temp extremes), the answer is years. I still have one of the original raspberry pi's from 2012 running today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspberry Pi only draws a maximum of 5W. This means the electricity bills of a raspberry pi would be **extremely** low.

This makes it an extremely good device for running small servers, bots, websites etc.

So the approximate power bill for running this 24/7 in the US would be $5.2596 (per year)

Answer (score 1):

The Pi uses less than 5W (it depends on model and what it is doing).

Around here electricity costs 28c per kWh so I can run a Pi for 200 hours for less than 25c!

The Pi uses less than your TV on standby.

I have 3 Pi that run non-stop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. sry but 28c mean 28cent right???

Comment: Look at your local electricity costs.  200 hours of use is approximately one kWh.

Comment: Nowadays, most TVs use less than 1W, some less than 0,1W on standby...